# Can't figure out how to work out the correct partition to translate an upper sum into the correct integral for evaluation. Spivak Ch.22 - 9) ii

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

This question is directly related to a previous question I asked:

[Question from *Spivak Calculus*, Ch.22 - #9 i) - relationship between sequences and integration.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849359/question-from-spivak-calculus-ch-22-9-i-relationship-between-sequences)

My problem is I can't seem to work out how to get the correct partition for the following upper sum which I'm equating to a sequence.

The original expression we are asked to evaluate is:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{e} + \sqrt[n]{e^{2}} + \dots + \sqrt[n]{e^{2n}}}{n}$$

**EDIT:** This is the question directly from the textbook (here I am asking about part (ii):

[image]

A formula that can be deduced for this is:

$$a_{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(e^{\frac{i}{n}})^{2}$$

The problem I'm having is figuring out the correct way to express the partition. For the original question I found the formula to be:

$$a_{n} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}e^{\frac{i}{n}}}{n}$$

From which we can determine a partition to be of length $\frac{1}{n}$ over the interval $[0,1]$ (I think my original issue is I'm not even sure how this interval was determined to be the "right" one). But with this idea we arrive at:

$$\int_{x=0}^1 e^x \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n e^{i/n}.$$

I know for this question the interval is supposed to be $[0,2]$, but I haven't been able to formally work it out. From the expression I have above what I was expecting to arrive at was something of the form:

$$a_{n} = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(e^{\frac{i}{n}})^{2}$$

From which the interval would could be instantly seen. But that didn't occur for me. What is it that I'm missing in being able to work out the correct intervals?

Comment: I am confused. In the linked question the last summand is $\sqrt[n]{e^n}$ and not $\sqrt[n]{e^{2n}$. Also, $a_n$ does not coincide with the terms in your formula.

Comment: @supinf I edited this question to hopefully answer your concern

Comment: then the formula for $a_n$ is not correct. The first term should be $e^{\frac1n}$, not $(e^{\frac1n})^2$.

Comment: then how do I account for the $\sqrt[n]{e^{2n}}$ term in the second sum?

Comment: Are you asking about part (i) or part (ii)?

Comment: @Adam  I'm asking about part (ii) here.

Comment: @dc3rd Then a correct formula for $a_n$ should be $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{2n} e^{i/n}$

Comment: @Adam with this being the case, how would I now go about working out the correct partition? (This applies to actually both parts of the question)

Comment: For (ii), $\frac{1}{n}\sum^{2n}_{j=1}e^{i/n}$ is a Riemann sum for the integral $\int^2_0e^{x}\,dx$. 

- Consider  the partition $x_k=\frac{k}{n}$, $k=0,\ldots,2n$, of the interval $I=[0,2]$ (divide $I$ in $2n$ pieces of the same length.  
- The Riemann sum one gets by taking the right-hand endpoints if the subintervals $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ ($k=1,\ldots,n$) generated by this partition is
$$\frac{2}{2n}\sum^{2n}_{k=1}e^{\tfrac{2}{2n}k}\approx\int^2_0 e^x\,dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for a partition $x_k:=a+\frac{b-a}{N}k$, $k=0,\ldots,M$ , of an interval $[a,b]$ and a function $f$,
$$
\frac{b-a}{N}\sum^N_{k=1}f(x_k)=h\sum^N_{k=1}f\big(a+kh), \qquad h=\frac{b-a}{N}
$$
is a Riemann approximation to $\int^b_a f(x)\,dx$

---

For (ii), $\frac{1}{n}\sum^{2n}_{j=1}e^{i/n}$ can be seen as a Riemann sum for the integral $\int^2_0e^{x}\,dx$.

- Consider  the partition $x_k=\frac{k}{n}$, $k=0,\ldots,2n$, of the interval $I=[0,2]$ (divide $I$ in $2n$ pieces of the same length.
- The Riemann sum one gets by taking the right-hand endpoints if the subintervals $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ ($k=1,\ldots,n$) generated by this partition is
  $$\frac{2}{2n}\sum^{2n}_{k=1}e^{\tfrac{2}{2n}k}\approx\int^2_0 e^x\,dx=2\int^1_0 e^{2u}\,du$$
  via the change of variables $x=2u$.
- Not surprisingly, the  sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum^{2n}_{k=1}e^{\frac{k}{n}}$ can also bee seen as a Riemann sum for the integral  $2\int^1_0 e^{2x}\,dx$. Use the partition $t_k=\frac{k}{2n}$, $k=0,\ldots,2n$ of the interval $[0,1]$.  Then
  $$
  \frac{1}{n}\sum^{2n}_{k=1}e^{\frac{k}{n}}=\frac{2}{2n}\sum^{2n}_{k=1}e^{2\tfrac{k}{2n}}\approx 2\int^1_0e^{2u}\,dx$$

Comment: You're explanation is the one that brought the most clarity to my questions. So I'm going to award the bounty to you. Thank you for your help as it has provided me with a needed clarity for tackling these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 3):

Partition the interval $[0,1]$ into $2n$ evenly spaced subintervals, so the partition is $\{0, \frac{1}{2n}, \frac{2}{2n}, \dots, \frac{2n-1}{2n}, 1 \}$.  Let $f(x) = e^{2x}$.  Then the Riemann sum for $f$ over $[0,1]$, using the right endpoints, is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{2n} f(i/2n) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^{2n} e^{i/n} = \frac{1}{2} a_n.
$$
(where $a_n$ is the formula for the $n$th term of the sequence in part (ii) of the question you posted).  Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ you get
$$
\int_0^1 e^{2x} \,dx = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We define
$$
b_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{2n} (e^{i/n}).
$$
We want to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ using the method you proposed,
using the interval $[0,2]$

We have
$$
b_n = \frac2{2n} \sum_{i=1}^{2n} e^{(2i)/(2n)}.
$$
If we define $c_m$ via
$$
c_m = \frac1{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} 2e^{(2i)/m}
$$
then one can see that $b_n=c_{2n}$.
Note that $b_n$ has the same limit as $c_m$ (if $c_m$ converges),
so we only need to calculate $\lim c_m$.
Then you can calculate $\lim c_{m}$ using the usual method:

We use the function $f(x)=2(e^{x})$ on the interval
$[0,2]$, and partition this interval into $n$ equal parts.
Then we have
$
c_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f((2i)/n),
$
which corrresponds to the integral $\int_0^2 f(x)$.

**What interval is the right one?**:

There is not always a right interval, and if one wishes, one can also use other intervals.
I used $[0,2]$ since it was mentioned in the question.

A good way to find the interval is to first guess the function
(in this case $f(x)=e^x$, but other functions would be also possible).
Then the interval boundaries $s,t$ should be chosen such that
$f(s)$ is close to the first summand (here, $e^{1/n} \sim e^0$ for large $n$),
and $f(t)$ is close to the last summand (here, $e^{{2n}/n} \sim e^2$ for all $n$).
Then one would choose the interval $[s,t]$ and continue working from there.

Comment: A major part of my issue was actually determining the proposed interval of $[0,2]$ (or $[0,1]$ from part (i)) and how we then translate that to the integral form.

Comment: @dc3rd I edited my answer to write a bit about the step towards integration. Could you go into more details what parts of my answer need more details?

Comment: @dc3rd I added something about determining the right interval for the integration. Note that this is not an exact science, just a rough method. If one has the right interval, then one can start working accurately.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for providing the explanation that you did, it assisted me in getting clarity, but there was another explanation that really got me over the hump and that is the one I'm going to be awarding the bounty to.